# How can I load a yaml file content in a dictionary containing placeholders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

Input yaml file

```
kind: Testing

metadata:

   name: test-file

   annotations:

      purpose: To test the deployed code

spec:
   containers:

     - name: client

       image: {{.registry}}/xyz:{{.client}}

       env:

         {{ if ne .proxy ""  }}

         - name: http_proxy

         value: "{{.proxy}}"

         {{ end -}}
```

I want to load all yaml content except the placeholder content in a dictionary. How can I achieve it? Can I use any regular expression to filter placeholders.

I tried using the following code, it works for the yaml which does not have placeholder values but gives parsing error with above yaml.

```
def __load_yaml(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
    try:
        return yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exception:
        raise exception
 
 def main():
   data = {}
   data.update(__load_yaml(file))
   print(data)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I also tried this, it is loading yaml to dictionary, but also giving FileNotFoundError. Is there any way to read list as stream? or any suggestion how can I achieve it?:

```
def __load_yaml(filename):

with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
    try:
        data = []
        for text in stream:
            match = re.search(r'\{\{.*?\}\}', text)
            if not match and text != None:
                data.append(text)
        with open(str(data), 'r') as stream:
            return yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exception:
        raise exception
```

Comment: `stream` is shadowed.

Comment: Can you suggest other way to load yaml by escaping the placeholders which matches regex @Jan ? I think it´s not way I should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __load_yaml(filename):
  with open(filename, "r") as stream:
    string = stream.read()
    # Find placeholders
    reg_one = re.findall(r':\{\{.*?\}\}', string)
    reg_two = re.findall(r'\{\{.*?\}\}', string)
    placeholders = reg_one + reg_two
    # Replace placeholders
    for placeholder in placeholders:
        string = string.replace(placeholder, "")
    try:
        return yaml.load(string, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exception:
        raise exception
```